# Return tuples if and only if the rest of the tuple all match

Tags: mysql, sql

My goal is to output a table that contains objects which their Data1 and Data2 pairs must all be equal. For example, in tables below, A is in two tuples where 2=2 and 1=1, and there does not exist a tuple for A that Data1 <> Data2. B has 4=4 however 3 <> 1 so it will not be output.
I can't simply use `WHERE Data1=Data2` otherwise | B | 4 | 4 | will be included as well.

```
SELECT * FROM Table
```

| Obj | Data1 | Data2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 2 |
| A | 1 | 1 |
| B | 3 | 1 |
| B | 4 | 4 |
| C | 5 | 6 |
| C | 7 | 8 |

Expected result:

| Obj | Data1 | Data2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 2 |
| A | 1 | 1 |

Comment: This table is a part of joined query table if that matters

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with u as 
(select Obj, 
Data1, 
Data2,
sum(case when Data1 <> Data2 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by Obj) as r
from table_name)
select Obj, Data1, Data2 from u
where r = 0
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b5320a7f1d2f7009b7427accd070ffc6)

Basically using the `sum` window function with a `case` expression to get `r` the number of times `Data1 <> Data2` for each `Obj`, then only selecting rows with `r = 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH CTE(Obj,   Data1 , Data2) AS
(
  SELECT 'A' ,  2 , 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'A' ,  1 , 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' ,  4 , 4 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C' ,  5 , 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C' ,  7 , 8 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B' ,    3,  1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C' ,  5 , 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C' ,  7 , 8
)
 SELECT C.Obj,C.Data1,C.Data2
 FROM CTE AS C
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
   SELECT 1 FROM CTE AS X
  WHERE C.Obj=X.Obj AND X.Data1<>X.Data2
 )
```